# Braintree payments Escrow Funding

Tags: php, braintree

I am trying to implement escrow funding using braintree in php. I have downloaded library from [here](https://www.braintreepayments.com/docs/php). My code is below:-

```
require_once "../braintree/lib/Braintree.php";

Braintree_Configuration::environment("sandbox");
Braintree_Configuration::merchantId("was4zgn5x6vt99h");
Braintree_Configuration::publicKey("ydjrasdwyw9npkvnw4");
Braintree_Configuration::privateKey("f197ac5a66a1fsad37d3950890b2cbda9");

$result = Braintree_Transaction::sale(
  array(
'amount' => "100.00",

'creditCard' => array(
  'number' => "4111111111111111",
  'expirationDate' => "12/2014",
),
'options' => array(
  'submitForSettlement' => true,
  'holdInEscrow' => true,
)

  )
    );
echo "<pre>";
 print_r("\n  message: " . $result->message);
```

It is working for direct payment. But It is not working for escrow. Please check my code.

Error is:-

```
"message: Transaction could not be held in escrow."
```

I have got the code from [here](https://www.braintreepayments.com/docs/php/transactions/escrow)

Comment: It seems, that it's not your code error. They can't process this transaction as escrow.

Comment: I am not clear what are you saying. Please give me some links that can help me..

Comment: If those are your real keys, you're probably going to want to change them...

Comment: Thanks @BradWerth, no these are not my real keys. COuld you please suggest me something about braintree escrow.......

Comment: @Bik Did you ever figure it out? I'm having the same issue

Comment: @DevinDixon Yes i have the answer. I will post it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

At last i got the actual answer from Braintree. I had to add two more parameters. One `merchantAccountId` and other is `serviceFeeAmount`. Here `merchantAccountId` id is actually sub merchant `merchantAccountId`. You will get `merchantAccountId` from Braintree. After logging in, go to **settings->Processing**. At the bottom of the page you will get **View All Merchant Account**. Here you will get merchantAccountId. Don't use default merchantAccountId it will not work.

```
require_once "../braintree/lib/Braintree.php";
Braintree_Configuration::environment("sandbox");
Braintree_Configuration::merchantId("was4zgn5x6vt99h");
Braintree_Configuration::publicKey("ydjrasdwyw9npkvnw4");
Braintree_Configuration::privateKey("f197ac5a66a1fsad37d3950890b2cbda9");

$result = Braintree_Transaction::sale(
  array(
'amount' => "100.00",
'merchantAccountId' => 'test_user_instant_5vcgn574',
'creditCard' => array(
  'number' => "4111111111111111",
  'expirationDate' => "12/2014",
),
'options' => array(
  'submitForSettlement' => true,
  'holdInEscrow' => true,
),
'serviceFeeAmount' =>'1'

  )
);
echo "<pre>";
print_r("\n  message: " . $result->message);
```

Answer (score 4):

I think that you need two things:

1. Pass a merchant_account_id - see example on https://www.braintreepayments.com/docs/php/transactions/escrow
2. You can only do escrow if your merchant account is using Marketplace. https://www.braintreepayments.com/docs/php/guide/marketplace

Answer (score 2):

I think you made a mistake in your code:

```
'options' => array(
  'submitForSettlement' => true,
  'holdInEscrow' => true,
)
```

Should be:

```
'holdInEscrow' => true
```

There should be no comma after `'holdInEscrow' => true`

Comment: That's irrelevant, trailing commas in arrays doesn't affect to the result